# What was the date 180 days ago?

Tags: c#, date

How would I get the date 180 days ago using C#?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
DateTime oneEightyAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-180);
```

Comment: I would use DateTime.Today as opposed to DateTime.Now because Today is just the date with 00:00 as the time, and now is the moment in time down to the millisecond

Comment: This is probably the most insightful answer I've seen yet on SO - cheers

Comment: Thanks, the whole DateTime.Today and DateTime.Now is a sticking point for me, especially in code review.  It's the whole concept of doing it the right way as opposed to a solution that happens to work (Programming by Coincidence - The Pragmatic Programmer)

Answer (score 9):

EDIT:

```
DateTime day180 = Date.Now.AddDays(-180);
```

It's important to put it into a separate variable otherwise the value will be lost.

Comment: Pretty sure he doesn't want to know what the date was 180 **months** ago. ;)

Comment: He wants days back, not months back.

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime oneEightyAgo = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-180);
```

Its best to record UTC...

Comment: There is also DateTime.UtcNow for that.

Answer (score 6):

DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180)

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180)`