# Powershell's Get-date: How to get Yesterday at 22:00 in a variable?

Tags: powershell

For a check i need yesterday's date at 10:00pm in a variable.

I get yesterdays Date and current Time with

```
$a = (get-date).AddDays(-1)
```

But how do i manipulate the time to 22.00 and leave the variable still as Date-Object?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use DateTime.Today as opposed to DateTime.Now (which is what Get-Date returns) because Today is just the date with 00:00 as the time, and now is the moment in time down to the millisecond. (from [masenkablast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319633/c-what-was-the-date-180-days-ago/2319655#2319655))

```
> [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(22)
Thursday, March 11, 2010 10:00:00 PM
```

Comment: wow I have this long complicated function in one of my scripts that does what this 1 line does. Yay for stupidity on my part.

Answer (score 18):

I see this topic, but in my case I was looking for a way to improve the format. Using UFormat and adding -1 day

```
(Get-Date (Get-Date).addDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
(Get-Date (Get-Date -Format d)).AddHours(-2)
```

Answer (score 5):

I saw in at least one other place that people don't realize `Date-Time` takes in times as well, so I figured I'd share it here since it's really short to do so:

```
Get-Date # Following the OP's example, let's say it's Friday, March 12, 2010 9:00:00 AM
(Get-Date '22:00').AddDays(-1) # Thursday, March 11, 2010 10:00:00 PM
```

It's also the shortest way to strip time information and still use other parameters of `Get-Date`. For instance you can get seconds since 1970 this way (Unix timestamp):

```
Get-Date '0:00' -u '%s' # 1268352000
```

Or you can get an ISO 8601 timestamp:

```
Get-Date '0:00' -f 's' # 2010-03-12T00:00:00
```

Then again if you reverse the operands, it gives you a little more freedom with formatting with any date object:

```
'The sortable timestamp: {0:s}Z{1}Vs measly human format: {0:D}' -f (Get-Date '0:00'), "`r`n"
# The sortable timestamp: 2010-03-12T00:00:00Z
# Vs measly human format: Friday, March 12, 2010
```

However if you wanted to both format a Unix timestamp (via `-u` aka `-UFormat`), you'll need to do it separately. Here's an example of that:

```
'ISO 8601: {0:s}Z{1}Unix: {2}' -f (Get-Date '0:00'), "`r`n", (Get-Date '0:00' -u '%s')
# ISO 8601: 2010-03-12T00:00:00Z
# Unix: 1268352000
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Format in other syntax is possible in this way

`[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: THAT'S THE GOOD ONE

Answer (score 3):

When I was to get yesterday with just the date in the format `Year/Month/Day` I use:

```
$Variable = Get-Date((get-date ).AddDays(-1))  -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do this:

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date.AddHours(22)
```

Comment: You might as well do `(Get-Date).Date.AddHours(-2)`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method but Unix timestamp

```
 ([int64](Get-Date -UFormat %s) - [int64](New-TimeSpan -Hours 1).TotalSeconds)
```